# Logging for Supervisord

Tags: logging, supervisord

I have a question about logging settings in the supervisord.conf file. Our server at work is running version 3.0b1 currently, and we have logfile_backups and logfile_maxbytes set to certain values under [supervisord]. Which is all fine and good.

My question, though, is if I include those flags under a child process, does it override what is set up at the top?

Here are some snippits of the config file to illustrate what I'm asking...

```
[supervisord]
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisord/
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB       ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10          ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info               ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false              ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                 ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)


[program:ParserClient]
command=/usr/local/bin/php /my/script/file.php --log-level=debug ;
process_name=%(program_name)s ;
numprocs=1                 ;
autostart=true             ;
autorestart=true           ;
startsecs=2                ;
logfile_maxbytes=10MB      ;
logfile_backups=1          ;
```

To sum up: does the logfile_maxbytes and logfile_backups established under [ParserClient] override the flags set up under [supervisord]?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is *no support* for `logfile_maxbytes` and `logfile_backups` for `[program:x]` sections, and supervisord ignores these options altogether in such sections.

You probably meant to specify the `stdout_logfile_maxbytes`, `stderr_logfile_maxbytes`, `stdout_logfile_backups` and / or `stderr_logfile_backups` options instead. These options do not take `[supervisord]` settings into account, you have to set them explicitly.

Comment: This appears to have changed: http://supervisord.org/logging.html#child-process-logs . You can now have `stdout_logfile_backups` and `stderr_...`

Comment: @raylu: that's what my answer states. The OP was using the `logfile_` prefix instead of using `stdout_logfile_*` and `stderr_logfile_*`.

Comment: Oh whoops. Reading comprehension failure.